# Finding the inner-most path of a polygon

Tags: algorithm, lua, polygon, graph-theory

Given an undirected graph of vertices, I need to find the innermost path that connects two specific points. My original idea was to just use something like Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path, but there are many cases where the shortest path is not the innermost. Here is a visual of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: 1]

Ultimately, I am trying to generate "rooms" based on walls that are drawn in my program. So in this image, the dashed line is the final edge I am drawing, which should then find an edge path from vertex 1 to vertex 7 (occluding the dashed edge), which would give me the path 1-2-3-4-5-6-7. If I was to use my current solution, the shortest path would be 1-2-8-6-7, but obviously, this is not the innermost path.

I've attempted to research this extensively but can't seem to find an answer. I also tried to pick the lowest edge angle at each node to traverse but this would only work for traveling in one direction, as I have no current way of determining whether it traverses clockwise or counterclockwise across the nodes. It might be worth noting that I am attempting this in Lua, but pseudo-code or a similarly high-level language would be appreciated as well!

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Start by calculating angle (0-360) of each directed edge.

Comment: `I have no current way of determining whether it traverses clockwise or counterclockwise` - you may receive two different solutions: clockwise and counterclockwise, both are "innermost"

Comment: Is this a [planar straight-line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight-line_graph)?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want is to enumerate the edges incident to a face of a planar straight-line graph.

First you need an embedding: for each node, sort the edges entering it in some counterclockwise order, e.g., 5→6, 8→6, 12→6, 7→6. (You can avoid trig if you like using the law of cosines.) Then store the successors in a big map: (5→6): (8→6), (8→6): (12→6), (12→6): (7→6), (7→6): (5→6), (1→7): (6→7), etc.

Second, to find the face to the right of a directed edge, repeatedly find the next directed edge in counterclockwise order and reverse it, until you come back to the starting edge. For example, 1→7, 6→7, 7→6, 5→6, 6→5, 4→5, 5→4, 3→4, 4→3, 2→3, 3→2, 1→2, 2→1, 7→1, 1→7.

Now, there's a slight complication here in that if you start with 7→1, you're going to loop around the infinite face: 7→1, 10→1, 1→10, 9→10, etc. The way to handle this is by computing the signed area of the face. If it's negative, then we're good, because we enumerate the finite faces in clockwise order. If it's positive, then we need the other face, because we enumerate the infinite face in counterclockwise order.

You'll have to tell me what you want if both incident faces are finite.

Comment: Is there any way you can explain how I would compute the signed area of the face? Or direct me to a resource that would better explain that concept?

Comment: @user1092481290841204 https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html